# Konsole font truncation - only with consolas

Tags: linux, fonts, kde, kde-4, konsole

When I use Consolas (of any size) as my terminal font, any pixels which hang below the line (such as the tail of a y) get truncated. Look at the second line in the screenshot below. Notice that the bottom of the square brackets and the tail of the p is missing.

[image: Truncated font]

But would like to see this:

[image: Non-truncated font]

(Though obviously with the Consolas font rather than Deja Vu.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is possible.

This reminds me of a [blog post on the Old New Thing.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070516-00/?p=26843)

While it is about Windows, I find it possible and likely that this applied to KDE as they would run into the same kinds of issues implementing fonts on the console.

Comment: I should perhaps mention that this used to be working for me until I rebooted today.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in konsole.

Try enabling bi-directional text rendering in Settings->Configure Current Profile->Advanced.

Comment: I tried doing this, and things got a little bizarre. Spacing was messed up, and alignment was skewed (similar to if you choose a non-monospaced font). However, technically it wasn't truncated, either...